# Enumeration with xlop

Tags: enumerate, xlop

I am creating problems for elementary level math, and I wish to enumerate the problems.  When I use the *xlop* package and enumerate, the enumeration occurs at the bottom left of the problem instead of the top left where I want it.  For example, when I write:

```
\item \opadd[resultstyle=\color{white},carrystyle=\color{white}]{563}{278}
```

the enumeration occurs on the on the bottom left.  Any solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the option `voperation=top`, see the [`xlop` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xlop) section 2.2.2 *General Displaying* for details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop,xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \opadd[voperation=top,resultstyle=\color{white},carrystyle=\color{white}]{563}{278}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This can also be set with `\opset` (in the preamble for example) so you don't have to repeat it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop,xcolor}
\opset{voperation=top}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \opadd[resultstyle=\color{white},carrystyle=\color{white}]{563}{278}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had a look when the package was new and vaguely remembered it had an option for this :)